# React removeEventListener not being removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have already looked through a lot of Googling, but still can't manage to fix this issue.

I've got a list of buttons that I want to be able to be selected by keypresses. When pressing "A", you get "A: Xxxxxxxx" `select` selected. When pressed B, you get "B: yyyyyyyy" `select` selected.

```
  const d = useDispatch();
  const s = useSelector(select);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(s);

  const eventHandler = function (card, i, setSelected, d, set) {
    return e => {
      if (alphabet.indexOf(e.key) === i) {
        setSelected(card.key);
        d(set(card.key));
      }
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    cards.map((card, i) => {
      window.addEventListener(
        "keypress",
        eventHandler(card, i, setSelected, d, set),
        false
      );
    });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keypress", eventHandler, false);
    };
  }, []);
```

Now, i found out, that you need to specify function references for them in order to work, but I can't get my head around how would I pass these variables from `cards.map` into the function `eventHandler` that handles the button presses? I'm really lost here...

Comment: Adding an event for every card is not the best design. One event handler can do the same exact thing.

Comment: `window.addEventListener` is a global event. You are trying to add a global event multiple times. If you want to listen on particular `div` do it by adding `domElement.addEventListener("keypress", callback);` . You can also do that in jsx like `onKeypress="method()"`

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan I want this to be accessible in the entire window.

Comment: @epascarello how do I get the variable references from the cards.map() then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a bunch of event listeners to the window. You need to store the events into something and reference them to remove them.

```
const myEvents = []
const eventHandler = function (card, i, setSelected, d, set) {
  const fnc = e => {
    if (alphabet.indexOf(e.key) === i) {
      setSelected(card.key);
      d(set(card.key));
    }
  };
  myEvents = fnc
  return fnc
};

useEffect(() => {
  cards.map((card, i) => {
    window.addEventListener(
      "keypress",
      eventHandler(card, i, setSelected, d, set),
      false
    );
  });
  return () => {
    myEvents.forEach(evt => 
      window.removeEventListener("keypress", evt, false))
  };
}, []);
```

In the end this code is really inefficient. You should be binding one event handler and looking up to see if the key matches any of the cards.

Basic idea would be

```
const lookUpCard = e => {
  const index = alphabet.indexOf(e.key)
  const myCard = cards[index]
})

window.addEventListener("keypress", lookUpCard)
```

Comment: >looking up to see if the key matches any of the cards
How would I find the reference for these cards? Because outside of cards.map(), i won't be able to get any references to them properly. Hard-coding would work, but it's not the best solution, as the component is reusable and depends on what type of info comes from API

Comment: Edited it with the basic idea, there are other ways to do it also. It would depend on the model you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I came up with something similar. Accepting @epascarello's answer as accepted because he gave me the basic idea.

```
  export const alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];

  const d = useDispatch();
  const s = useSelector(select);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(s);

  const keyPressHandler = (event) => {
    const index = alphabet.indexOf(event.key);
    if (index >= 0) {
      setSelected(cards[index].key);
      d(set(cards[index].key));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler, false);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler, false);
    };
  });
```